# Create files matching a column value

Tags: bash, awk

I have a text file similar to below

```
https://hosted.example.com [403]
https://checkout.example.com [200]
https://lib.example.com [403]
http://autodiscover.example.com [301]
https://go.example.com [503]
https://qa.example.com [403]
https://qalib.example.com [403]
https://join.example.com [200]
```

The file has similar lines with status codes in the second column like the above sample data. I want to create files based on the second column, if the second column has a value of 200 then that line has to be redirected to 200.txt and this follows with every status code.

Script used:

```sh
list=('[403] [401] [404] [503] [301] [302] [200]')
for i in $list
do
filename=$(echo $i | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)
awk '$2 == "$i"' file.txt | awk '{print $1}' > $filename.txt
done
```

The problem with the script is it create files but the value of column 1 is not redirected to the respective files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `awk` should work for you:

```sh
awk '{gsub(/[][]/, "", $2); print $1 > ($2 ".txt")}' file

ls *.txt
200.txt  301.txt  403.txt  503.txt
```

Comment: This is a clean solution as always

Comment: @EdMorton  there are no `[` & `]` in urls and as of now the file has only 7 unique status codes , which may rise but not above 8 or 10, so  I dont think it will be an issue

Comment: @JoelDeleep you should add that information to your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F'[][]' '{close(out); out=$(NF-1)".txt"; sub(/ [^ ]+$/,""); print >> out}'
```

the above allows for `[` and/or `]` in the URL and won't fail with "too many open files" once you get past a limit with non-gawk awks.

With respect to `'$2 == "$i"'` in the script in  your question - see [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script).

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
awk '
/^https?/ && match($0,/\[[0-9]+\]/){
  outputFile=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)".txt"
}    
NF{
  print >> (outputFile)
  close(outputFile)
}
' Input_file
```

Comment: I tried and got `awk: null file name in print or getline
 input record number 1, file file.txt
 source line number 6` 

But why my code is not working ?

Comment: @JoelDeleep, Ok, could you please try my edited code and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: @JoelDeleep, This is a well tested command with your shown samples. Please do let me know if your actual Input is different from shown smaples?

Comment: there is no difference in the input

Comment: @JoelDeleep, ok, could you please do run a `cat -vet file` on your file to check if you have Control M characters in it?

Comment: `https://hosted.example.com [403]$` every line had $ at the end with that command.

Comment: A string like `[27]` can exist within a URL btw so YMMV with assuming it can't.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer I have as far as I understood the question.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -r col1 col2; do
  printf '%s %s\n' "$col1" "$col2" > "${col2//[][]}".txt
done < file.txt
```

That will overwrite the contents of the existing file if the value inside `[ ]` is a match, or rather if there are duplicate values.

Comment: This worked, may I know why my code didnt work ?

Comment: You may paste your code at https://shellcheck.net for starters.

Comment: The shell variable may or may not be interpreted by `awk` , also piping `awk` to `awk` is not really needed since awk can do it all.